# While Loop encrypted data

Tags: php, mysql, database, encryption, while-loop

I'm trying to pass encrypted data through a while loop, in order to decrypt the data from a database. I'm able to get some what of a result. Though, since the decryption relies on if the string matches the key. If it the key doesn't match, it won't display anything because all of the strings combine, instead of breaking on each table line.

**What I'm seeing happen:**

If encrypted data line 1 is: **1234**

If encrypted data line 2 is: **5678**

```
+-------------------+
| client_name       |
+-------------------+
| 1234              |
| 5678              |
+-------------------+
```

The result with the while loop is: **12345678**. What I'm trying to achieve is having the while loop go line to line and output for decryption.

Here is what I have for the while loop output:

```
<?php
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM invoices WHERE username = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
    {
    $security = new Security();
    echo "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>".$security->decrypt($info['client_name'])." <span class='label label-default pull-right'>Invoice 20</span></a>";
  }
?>
```

Here is what I have for the decryption: (Based on - http://wpy.me/blog/15-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-in-php-using-aes-256)

```
<?php class Security {

            # Private key
            public static $salt = 'ZfTfbipGsZ4yz34jFrGHagahptzLN7ROigy';


            # Encrypt a value using AES-256.
            public static function encrypt($plain, $key = null, $hmacSalt = null) {
                if(empty($key)) {
                    $key = self::$salt;
                }

                self::_checkKey($key, 'encrypt()');

                if ($hmacSalt === null) {
                    $hmacSalt = self::$salt;
                }

                $key = substr(hash('sha256', $key . $hmacSalt), 0, 32); # Generate the encryption and hmac key

                $algorithm = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128; # encryption algorithm
                $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC; # encryption mode

                $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size($algorithm, $mode); # Returns the size of the IV belonging to a specific cipher/mode combination
                $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM); # Creates an initialization vector (IV) from a random source
                $ciphertext = $iv . mcrypt_encrypt($algorithm, $key, $plain, $mode, $iv); # Encrypts plaintext with given parameters
                $hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext, $key); # Generate a keyed hash value using the HMAC method
                return $hmac . $ciphertext;
            }

            # Check key
            protected static function _checkKey($key, $method) {
                if (strlen($key) < 32) {
                    echo "Invalid key $key, key must be at least 256 bits (32 bytes) long."; die();
                }
            }

            # Decrypt a value using AES-256.
            public static function decrypt($cipher, $key = null, $hmacSalt = null) {
                if(empty($key)) {
                    $key = self::$salt;
                }

                self::_checkKey($key, 'decrypt()');

                if (empty($cipher)) {
                    echo 'The data to decrypt cannot be empty.'; die();
                }
                if ($hmacSalt === null) {
                    $hmacSalt = self::$salt;
                }

                $key = substr(hash('sha256', $key . $hmacSalt), 0, 32); # Generate the encryption and hmac key.

                # Split out hmac for comparison
                $macSize = 64;
                $hmac = substr($cipher, 0, $macSize);
                $cipher = substr($cipher, $macSize);

                $compareHmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $cipher, $key);
                if ($hmac !== $compareHmac) {
                    return false;
                }

                $algorithm = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128; # encryption algorithm
                $mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC; # encryption mode
                $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size($algorithm, $mode); # Returns the size of the IV belonging to a specific cipher/mode combination

                $iv = substr($cipher, 0, $ivSize);
                $cipher = substr($cipher, $ivSize);
                $plain = mcrypt_decrypt($algorithm, $key, $cipher, $mode, $iv);
                return rtrim($plain, "\0");
            }

        }
?>
```

What would you suggest I do within my while loop, to output each data point separately?

Comment: I don't really get the problem? It is going line for line now. It's just the "echo" that echoes it on the same line. Add a `<br />` for each iteration? And you should put the instantiation of the Security class before the while loop.

Comment: I think your problem is that you don't get the output on separate lines, but I'm not really sure. Could be that you are having problem with decryption as it looks like your output is the same as input. If all you want is separate lines then perhaps adding ´echo "<p></p>" ´ would help?

Comment: in your code you're trying to decrypt with a 128bit algorithm YET you're checking for a keylength of 256 bits .... does not compute, your code will never work correctly. At all.

Comment: ...and you shouldn't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions. Use mysqli or PDO with prepared statements instead.

Answer (score -1):

Just do like this:

```
if($data->num_rows() > 0){
   // create her security object not inside loop.
   $security = new Security();

   foreach($data->result() as $row){
       echo "<a href='#' class='list-group-item'>".$security->decrypt($row->client_name)." <span class='label label-default pull-right'>Invoice 20</span></a><br/>";
   }
}
```

Comment: You really should explain what you're doing and not just post a piece of code. We should help each other learn, not just do their jobs for them.

Comment: Another thing... `$data->result()`... what is that? `$data` is a mysql result resource which doesn't have any `::result()` method, as far as I know?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sorry for that, i'm working with `Codeigniter` and it was syntax of codeigniter.